# TensorFlow Estimator Confusion Matrix

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to Tensorflow and I just ran my first Neural Network classifier which I got the code from https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/estimator.
It worked successfully but it only showed the precision.
How can I output the confusion matrix? I have 2 labels only. 1 and 0.

This is the last part of the code. It is the same as the link.

```
  # Train model.
  classifier.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=2000)

  # Define the test inputs
  test_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
      x={"x": np.array(test_set.data)},
      y=np.array(test_set.target),
      num_epochs=1,
      shuffle=True)

  # Evaluate accuracy.
  accuracy_score = classifier.evaluate(input_fn=test_input_fn)["accuracy"]
```

Comment: But the code in the link has some more lines, including `predictions = list(classifier.predict(input_fn=predict_input_fn))`. Don't these lines give you what you want? If you want the confusion matrix on the test data, replace `predict_input_fn` with `test_input_fn` in these lines

Comment: I am getting results like New Samples, Class Predictions:    [array([b'0'], dtype=object), array([b'0'], dtype=object), array([b'0'].

Comment: How can I produce the True Positives, False Positives... results

Answer (score 3):

You can generate a confusion matrix using [`tf.confusion_matrix`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/confusion_matrix). In particular, something like the following should work:

```
labels = list(test_set.target)
predictions = list(classifier.predict(input_fn=test_input_fn))
confusion_matrix = tf.confusion_matrix(labels, predictions)
```

Answer (score 2):

There might be a little more to it.

```
labels = list(test_set[label_column])
raw_predictions = regressor.predict(input_fn=get_input_fn(test_set)
predictions = [p['class_ids'][0] for p in raw_predictions]
confusion_matrix = tf.confusion_matrix(labels, predictions)
```

The raw prediction output is a dict of labels and probabilities.  You need to get the labels.

You might also need to add something like:

```
with tf.Session():
    print('\nConfusion Matrix:\n', tf.Tensor.eval(confusion_matrix,feed_dict=None, session=None))
```

In order to print the matrix